# Uninstalling Gulp globally (but not locally)

Tags: gulp

New to Gulp, somehow I installed different versions of Gulp globally and locally, triggering version mismatch warning messages. Is it possible for me to uninstall Gulp globally without affecting local installs?

Answer (score 20):

Yes you can.

You can uninstall using the -g flag, it will make sure only the global package is removed:

```sh
npm uninstall -g gulp
```

To remove a local package and remove it from the package.json dependencies property use:

```sh
npm uninstall package-name
```

To remove a local package and remove it from the package.json devDependencies property use:

```sh
npm uninstall -D package-name
```

Update:
As you may have noticed, running "gulp" in your terminal now produces an error
saying "No such file or directory"

You can just call the gulp executable directly. e.g:

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/gulp [arguments...]
```

Update: npm 5.2.0 and above comes with a new tool called 'npx'

Using the below command will look for the gulp binary for you:

```sh
npx gulp
```

Read more about npx in this [Medium post](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b).

Comment: It uninstalled gulp both locally and globally since now typing "gulp" in my local project folder yields "bash: /c/Program Files/nodejs/gulp: No such file or directory" :(

Comment: The reason you're see this error is that the local node_modules folder has a folder called ".bin" which is not exported in your shell's path. You need to add that folder to your path ( I'll include how to do that in my answer in a few moments. )

Comment: How do I export the ".bin" folder path to my terminal?

Comment: @Jeff In *Nix based shells: export PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH